# Efficient data rertrieval from SQL database

Tags: php, postgresql

I have 3 tables. One which holds reports of certain activities with path and object_id(not unique) and another table, by which I could get user id by object_id and a third one from which I could get the emails for the appropriate entries.

What I need is an array in the form of

```
email1 {
  objectid1 {
    path1
    path2
    ...
  }
  objectid2 {
    path3
    ...
  }
}
email2{
  ...
}
```

etc.

I thought of first retrieving emails with SELECT DISTINCT, then foreach of them get object_ids and foreach of these get paths, but this would result in an exponential amount of DB queries, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How would I implement join in the case? to get the results I need? It might be late and I might be slow thinking :/

for getting emails I do use join

Comment: Actually maybe I could just use joins to generate a bunch of rows joined with email and then parse it with PHP?

Comment: You really have not provided enough information in your question to get any guidance on how you can make a join query to get your data. At a minimum, you should put in information on your table schema as well as how those tables map to the data structure you desire.

Comment: Yep, you definitely want to use either LEFT or INNER joins, but we can't help you any further without more specific details of your table structure and exact expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it a bit differently, but got desired result, in the sense, that I can parse the data further as I want it. Solution:

```
 private function getrejects(){
 // Here I just got joined data with duplicate emails and object_ids        
    global $DBC;

    $qRecipients = pg_query($DBC,'
        SELECT
                users.email, objects.object_id, rejects.path, rejects.report_id
        FROM
                rejects                    
        LEFT JOIN
                objects 
        ON
                rejects.object_id = objects.object_id                           
        LEFT JOIN
                users
        ON
                objects.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE
                date_sent IS NULL

    ');

    $result = array();
    while($row =  pg_fetch_assoc($qRecipients)){
        array_push($result,$row);
    }

    return $result;

}
```

and here I put it into an array with the email and object_id as subsequent keys.

```
private function formatemaildata($in){

    foreach ($in as $row){            
        if (!isset($result[$row['email']][$row['object_id']])){
            $result[$row['email']][$row['object_id']]=array();
        }            
        array_push($result[$row['email']][$row['object_id']], $row['path']);
    }
    return $result;

}
```

The result while dumped is along the lines of

```
'test@email.com' =>
  array(3) {
    [8573] =>
    array(4) {
      [0] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
      [1] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
      [2] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
      [3] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
    }
    [8574] =>
    array(4) {
      [0] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
      [1] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
      [2] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
      [3] =>
      string(30) "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"
    }
```